# In the Swan Thong episode of Legends of Tomorrow, who were all those Hall of Villain members that were not named specifically?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In the season finale episode for Season 5 of *Legends of Tomorrow*, several villains from Hell were recalled to fight the heroes. Who were the ones that weren't named? The ones that were named were *Josef Stalin*, *Charles Manson*, *Marie Antoinette*, *Caligula*, and *Vlad the Impaler*.

The unnamed and uncredited ones were:

1. Caveman holding a rock over his head (Cain?)
2. elaborately bearded man dressed in a US Cavalry uniform from the Old West
3. dark haired man in ancient leather banded armor

Which historical villains are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

The guy in uniform is supposed to be Custer. The other two are never identified. Any names of villains from cave man days would be unknown to modern history anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the uniformed guy could have been Quentin Turbull. Were any of the un-named characters featured previously in other episodes? Named character like Marie Antoinette were.

Comment: The caveman did have a card in front of his exhibit, so he was at least known in that timeline. Anyone with a good zoom feature to get a look at the text on the card?